# Linux USB Disk Mirroring - Is this the right Approach?

Tags: linux, usb, backup, raid

I have a 1TB NTFS USB Data Drive (no boot, etc...) that I would like to keep a mirror of as a backup in case of hardware failure.

It is always connected to my raspberry pi running the raspbian (debian) based raspmc.

After reviewing this question... [How to set up disk mirroring in ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54960/how-to-set-up-disk-mirroring-in-ubuntu)

This seems like a good solution to mirror the drive.

- Will this work as expected for USB drives?
- Am I looking at any performance loss by mirroring the drive?
- Anything I'm not considering that I should be?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your USB is USB 3.0 your biggest problem is the USB 2.0 performance loss.  Using hard drives 30mb/s is the best I have ever seen is USB 2.0.  You will preferred death to copying a 50gb file over USB 2.0.  If all your files are relatively small it won't be that bad.  It will take 1 second to transfer 30mb, and will scale upward from there.

There is a software RAID 1 module built-in to the kernel.  As you plan to do mirroring and not RAID 2,3,4,5,6, or higher the software RAID 1 should not use much CPU, but will use some.